# Singular Value Decomposition (SVD): Intuition for $U$ and $V$

Tags: intuition, svd

I am trying to get a better intuition for $U$ and $V$ in the SVD. I have read [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/svd-8c2f72e264f) which describes $U$ as the normalized projection onto $V$. However, other explanations define $U$ as a rotation matrix that is derived through an eigenvalue decomposition of $AA'$ with $A$ being the to be decomposed matrix.

If it helps, I am looking at neural data and $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix with $m$ channels of each $n$ samples. Does that mean the components in $U$ are spatial filter and the components in $V$ are temporal filter? I simply cannot reconcile the above two interpretations of $U$ and $V$.

Thank you for your help,

Luca

Comment: One viewpoint is that if the columns of $V$ are $v_1, v_2, \ldots$ then $v_i$ maximizes $\| Av\|$ subject to the constraints that $\| v \| = 1$ and $v$ is orthogonal to $v_1, \ldots, v_{i-1}$. The columns of $V$ are the directions in which $A$ has the most explosive power or the most amplifying power. $V^T$ is the change of basis matrix from the standard basis to this special basis.